# Python\Numpy: Comparing arrays with NAN

Tags: python, numpy

Why are the following two lists not equal?

```
a = [1.0, np.NAN] 
b = np.append(np.array(1.0), [np.NAN]).tolist()
```

I am using the following to check for identicalness.

```
((a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b))).all(), np.in1d(a,b)
```

Using `np.in1d(a, b)` it seems the `np.NAN` values are not equal but I am not sure why this is. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: I felt @DSM's answer gave the workaround I was using and hence voted it as the top answer

Comment: I don't see how the question can be considered a duplicated, there might be others similar, but the question linked as duplicate is about IEEE implementation (why nan != nan) and doesn't even mention arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` are lists, `a == b` isn't returning an array, and so your numpy-like logic won't work:

```
>>> a == b
False
```

The command you've quoted only works if they're *arrays*:

```
>>> a,b = np.asarray(a), np.asarray(b)
>>> a == b
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b))
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> ((a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b))).all()
True
```

which should work to compare two arrays (either they're both equal or they're both NaN).

Comment: thanks just realised that. I'll attempt a workaround.

Answer (score 8):

`NaN` values never compare equal. That is, the test `NaN==NaN` is always `False` *by definition of `NaN`*.

So `[1.0, NaN] == [1.0, NaN]` is also `False`. Indeed, once a `NaN` occurs in any list, it cannot compare equal to any other list, even itself.

If you want to test a variable to see if it's `NaN` in `numpy`, you use the `numpy.isnan()` function. I don't see any obvious way of obtaining the comparison semantics that you seem to want other than by “manually” iterating over the list with a loop.

Consider the following:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def nan_eq(a, b):
    for i,j in zip(a,b):
        if i!=j and not (math.isnan(i) and math.isnan(j)):
            return False
    return True

a=[1.0, float('nan')]
b=[1.0, float('nan')]

print( float('nan')==float('nan') )
print( a==a )
print( a==b )
print( nan_eq(a,a) )
```

It will print:

```
False
True
False
True
```

The test `a==a` succeeds because, presumably, Python's idea that references to the same object are equal trumps what would be the result of the element-wise comparison that `a==b` requires.

Comment: thanks. It is weird because I can use `a = np.array([1.0, np.NAN]), b = np.append(np.array(1.0), [np.NAN])` works with `((a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b))).all()`

Comment: Actually the answer isn't entirely correct: a list containing NaN will compare equal to itself (although arguably it shouldn't) in Python.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: yes, indeed it does. I suspect that's because Python “short-cuts” the elementwise comparison and just returns `True` if you compare a list to itself, and that trumps the “correct” result. It seems like a reasonable optimization: no point in slowing every list compare-to-self down on the off-chance that there might be a NaN in there.

Comment: You can get a slightly faster version of `math.isnan(x)` by doing ` x != x`, which is how NumPy does this in the source C code, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L2456). So in pure Python you can do `all(j == k or (j != j and k != k) for j, k in zip(a, b))` to check for equality.

Comment: `a = [1, np.nan];
b = [1, np.nan]; a == b` returns True still. I cannot find why is that, though.

Comment: I was going to comment same thing. Lists seems to be smart enough with nan comparison, while arrays are not (shame for them).

Answer (score 0):

NaNs are implemented in python (and numpy) according to IEEE 754 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), and defined as unorderable.  In practice, this means that a NaN never returns True on an ordered compare operation, e.g. `<`, `>`, `==`, etc.  numpy and the buillting `math` module provide `isnan` functions to determine if a value is NaN.